# Java: How can I create good looking class docs with Javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc, doclet

I'd like to create HTML documentation for a Java class library that includes

- programming guide information - beyond just a class reference
- code examples in the reference doc
- collapsible regions

I want it to look well-styled.  Something like this:

[image]

I *think* that Javadoc exposes a doclet API that allows other parties to provide doc generation integrated in Javadoc. Is there a doclet option that I can use (for free) that does something a little nicer than the standard javadoc output?

I tried googling for this but no luck.
Suggestions?

**Addendum**
I found [doclet.com](http://www.doclet.com/) but I don't know how to evaluate the options. Recommendations?

In particular, [XHtmlDoclet](http://xhtmldoclet.sourceforge.net/faq.php) sounds like it wants to address these issues.  Anyone used it?  [I can't get it to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533556/java-xhtml-doclet-fatal-exception).  Also the [example offered by the XHTML Doclet guys](http://xhtmldoclet.sourceforge.net/newdocs/) doesn't look any better than [the docs generated from c.1998 javadoc](http://xhtmldoclet.sourceforge.net/javadoc/) .

---

Related:
[Why does Javadoc generate non-compliant XHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267140/why-does-javadoc-generate-non-compliant-xhtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question got me thinking (ok, Googling) and I stumbled on [this set of taglets](http://taglets.sourceforge.net/index.html). Never tried it, but it looks pretty promising.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're thinking of Java doclet API:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html

It appears that you're adding examples and some text.  I think it's entirely possible with existing javadocs.  The problem will be the content rather than the rendering.

[Castor](http://castordoclet.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html) used doclet to ease its config burden.  So did [EJB 1.0](http://xdoclet.sourceforge.net/xdoclet/ant/xdoclet/modules/ejb/EjbDocletTask.html).  Take a look at those if you'd like.

Comment: Changing the CSS should be trivial too.

Comment: @dummymo:  Well the doclet API allows additional doclet engines as far as I know.  In other words the generation is pluggable. I'm asking, what other doclets have been produced for generating API and guidance docs? 

@donal, ok, sounds easy. How?

Comment: You've got the output files, and javadoc uses a single CSS file in the root directory of the generated tree. If you can't work it out from there, I despair... ;–)

Comment: @Cheeso, why the switch to "dummymo"?  Not a good way to convince people to give you their best.

Comment: sorry, typo. my mistake. not intentional.

Comment: I'm not buying it.  "m" isn't close to "f" on my keyboard.

Comment: Ah, it's your choice whether to believe me or not!

Comment: That's right, it is, and I don't.  I've formulated another belief instead.