# Java XHTML Doclet: fatal exception

Tags: java, xhtml, doclet

Has anyone used [XHTML Doclet](http://xhtmldoclet.sourceforge.net/), and can you provide some hints as to how to get it to work successfully?

I run it like this:

```
\sunjdk\bin\javadoc -doclet net.sourceforge.xhtmldoclet.Doclet  
         -docletpath c:\sw\java\XHTML_Doclet_0.4.jar -d <output>
         [class files here]
```

(all on one line)

When I run it I get this:

```
javadoc: error - In doclet class net.sourceforge.xhtmldoclet.Doclet,  method validOptions has thrown an exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.Error: Fatal: Resource (net.sourceforge.xhtmldoclet.resources.doclet) for javadoc doclets is missing.
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.MessageRetriever.getText(MessageRetriever.java:110)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.MessageRetriever.getText(MessageRetriever.java:92)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.MessageRetriever.getText(MessageRetriever.java:81)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.Configuration.getText(Configuration.java:634)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.Configuration.generalValidOptions(Configuration.java:515)
        at net.sourceforge.xhtmldoclet.Config.validOptions(Unknown Source)
        at net.sourceforge.xhtmldoclet.Doclet.validOptions(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:269)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.validOptions(DocletInvoker.java:198)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:317)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:128)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:41)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:31)
1 error
```

It seems like it ought to just work. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XhtmlDoclet appears to have a bug in its resource handling. I've submitted a bug and a patch to fix it here:
https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3006429&group_id=199009&atid=967765

The bug happens when the doclet is trying to output user-visible text, so it's probably trying to print an error message which you can't see because of the bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
\sunjdk\bin\javadoc -classpath c:\sw\java\XHTML_Doclet_0.4.jar 
         -doclet net.sourceforge.xhtmldoclet.Doclet  
         -docletpath c:\sw\java\XHTML_Doclet_0.4.jar -d <output>
         [class files here]
```

all on one line

Comment: I had two much more complicated previous attempts at this!  One involving modifying tools.jar and one involving compiling doclet.properties but the above method works just fine!

Comment: This gives the same result, for me. . .